# Drools much slower than EasyScoreCalculator [OptaPlanner]

Tags: drools, optaplanner

Isn't Drools score calculation supposed to be faster than EasyScoreCalculator ?

Depending on the problem size I am working on I notice that Drools is 2-5x slower than EasyScoreCalculator.

e.g.
Drools

```
2019-09-04 04:53:47,681 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (86), best score (-306init/[0]hard/[0/0]soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2019-09-04 04:53:50,263 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (2671), best score ([0]hard/[9272/0]soft), score calculation speed (24149/sec), step total (306).
2019-09-04 04:54:02,592 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (15000), best score ([0]hard/[9272/0]soft), score calculation speed (31552/sec), step total (38993).
2019-09-04 04:54:02,593 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (15001), best score ([0]hard/[9272/0]soft), score calculation speed (30079/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

EasyScoreCalculator

```
2019-09-04 04:53:10,282 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (8), best score (-306init/[-306]hard/[0]soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2019-09-04 04:53:10,972 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (699), best score ([0]hard/[9272]soft), score calculation speed (90657/sec), step total (306).
2019-09-04 04:53:25,273 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (15000), best score ([0]hard/[9272]soft), score calculation speed (109948/sec), step total (193419).
2019-09-04 04:53:25,273 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (15000), best score ([0]hard/[9272]soft), score calculation speed (108976/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

The only Drools rule I am using in this test is as follows:

```
rule "Maximise number of picked up parcels"
    when
      $job: Job(vehicle != null && vehicle.getVehicleType() != VehicleType.DUMMY)
    then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, $job.getNumberOfParcels());
end
```

In EasyScoreCalculator this looks like:

```java
public void calculateScore(VehicleRoutingSolution solution) {

    int numberOfPickedUpParcels = 0;

    List<Job> jobsList = solution.getJobs();

    for (Job job : jobsList) {

      Vehicle vehicle = job.getVehicle();

      if (vehicle!= null) {
        if (VehicleType.DUMMY != vehicle.getVehicleType()) {
          numberOfPickedUpParcels += job.getNumberOfParcels();
        }

    }

    int[] constraints = new int[1];
    int[] objectives = new int[1];

    constraints[0] = 0;
    objectives[0] = numberOfPickedUpParcels;

    return BendableScore.of(constraints, objectives);
  }
```

Isn't this peculiar? Is it because my rule is inefficient or are there caveats when Drools score calculation will be slower than easy ?

**EDIT:**
This is a pretty late edit, but here is some data to back this up. Benchmarked the VRP datasets from [here](https://www.sintef.no/projectweb/top/vrptw/homberger-benchmark/) on various datasets from the 200, 600 and 1000 sized problemsets. While the performance of EasyScoreCalculator crashes for larger instances it is still faster than Drools.

Does it maybe have something to do with the amount of shadow variables there are in the problem? I remember running more complicated problems with more constraint when Drools did outperform EasyScoreCalculator, but that problem was more sophisticated.

[image]

**EDIT2**:
I have re-run the experiment using the same dataset as above. Somehow Drools scales better now. Not sure why it is faster this time around with no config changes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drools score calculation is incremental, so **it scales much better** than `EasyScoreCalculator` which is not incremental.

However, Drools does come with a performance overhead, so for smaller datasets, that overhead could undo the scaling gain. Use `optaplanner-benchmark` to try 3 different datasets, doubling in size each time, and look at the performance graph in the benchmark report.

Comment: Thanks for this answer back then. I have edited my answer and did what you suggested. Interestingly, for the problemsets I have tried EasyScoreCalculator remains faster although performance degrades quickly. Drools score performanse stays relatively stable so I think there would be a tipping point when Drools will be faster. I would have expected to reach that point by 1000 nodes, but interestingly EasyScoreCalculator is still faster than. Maybe in a more constrained problem Drools will outperform EasyScoreCalculator.

Comment: Yea, this is the main reason I started Bavet. Get your cake and eat it too. The poc works, but currently finishing it is on our backlog somewhere, de prioritized due to amount of work. Drools is improving. Cases like this do raise interesting questions...